# If telerik report viewer has no records then display a message

Tags: asp.net, telerik, reporting, reportviewer

I am developing a web application and I need to create a report using telerik report veiewer.
I am successully able to fetch and display records in report viewer. 
But if no records are found then it displays only the headers of all Fields.
Insted of these fields ,I want to display a message such as "No Records Available".

As well as I want to display all records in a single page in telerik report viewer, how?

Answer (score 1):

About the "No Data Message"
Select your fields/headers block

[image]

Look in properties for "No Data Message", it is just below Location...Modifiers..,
set your message like this or whatever you like but between '  ':

**Updated**
[image]

Thats it!

Concerning the other question, please be more specific. What you would like to keep in one page? Groups, all data? If one page is enough for your data, they will fit in one page otherwise more pages will be added and you have to format them to fit in one.
If instead you like to keep together a group then it is a different story. Be more specific.

Comment: Can u elaborate "No data are available" process.,

Comment: @Vino as I said above, Select the block with the headers and data cell as per my picture 1. Right click on it, Property, in the filed "No data Message" add your message. Thats all. In case of no data present in the datasource the message will show up and headers/cell fields will be hidden as per my picture 2.

Comment: while i'm selecting fields/headers block like above fig's property there is no option for "No data Message" . then what can i do?

Comment: No way! Which version of telerik are you using?

Comment: i'm using older version of the telerik reporting ie 7.1.13.802.,